# Bootstrap Star Rating doesn't work the first time

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this rating plugin - [Krajee](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?d8VUtmAN).
I have a phtml file. The rating is getting displayed fine and even working but it does not work on the first click. Here's what happens:

1. The stars are clicked once, nothing happens
2. Mouse out of that area.
3. Mouse in to that area to some location other than that where I clicked the first time.
4. Click on the stars, now it works.

I tried disabling all the other JS on the page thinking it maybe clashing with that but that didn't work either.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I could write a short, self-contained, correct example but that wouldn't be of much help since it's working fine in the demo I made to troubleshoot the issue. I know I am doing something wrong, I just want to know what.

Comment: unless you dont show us your code  or jsfiddle link its difficult to guess the issue.

Comment: I just need someone who has some experience in this to guide me regarding where I could be going wrong. And the code is offline anyway, so I couldn't show you the code even if I wanted to.

Comment: If it's offline, then just copy-paste it into [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). Without the code it's a guessing game.

Answer (score 1):

you can use raty.js for stars its built with jquery and you can easily modify apply ratings here is the link 
http://wbotelhos.com/raty